# Nested exhaustive pattern matching in Purescript

Tags: purescript

Consider my two attempts at writing the same function:

```
data Foo = Bar Int | Quux Int | Baz Int

f :: Foo -> Int
f (Bar n) = n
f other =
  case other of
    Quux n -> 2 * n
    Baz n -> 3 * n

g :: Foo -> Int
g foo =
  case foo of
    Bar n -> n
    other ->
      case other of
        Quux n -> 2 * n
        Baz n -> 3 * n
```

Neither `f` nor `g` compiles, because the case statement on `other` is non-exhaustive in each version.

Is there another way to write these functions such that the fact that `other` is statically known not to be of the `Bar` variant is used by the compiler to prove that the case statement is indeed exhaustive?

This can be worked around in various ways (e.g., by throwing an exception if `Bar` is encountered in the case statement), but I'd be interested in something that can be statically checked.

Comment: No, there is not

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is also about the fact that you only want to handle these two cases (`Quux` and `Baz`) further.

Therefore, you could simply add a case that recursively uses f again.
Because there is already the "base case" for `(Bar n)`.

```
f :: Foo -> Int
f (Bar n) = n
f other =
  case other of
    Quux n -> 2 * n
    Baz n -> 3 * n
    _ -> f other
```

The use of `_` means that every other case is processed with it.

But this is just a workaround to make the example compilable. You cannot create a function that only accepts `Quux` and `Baz` and not `Bar`.

Then you should separate these types:

```
data Foo = Quux Int | Baz Int

newtype Bar = Bar Int
```

So now you have to work with two types.